# keytool certificate generation appeats to hang in command line

Tags: java, command-line, keytool

Im having a potential issue, or possibly a lack of patience, using keytool in the command line. Ive created a keyStore successfully and i also generated a certificate request successfully. But when I attempt to generate the certificate from the request it appears to hang.

In the command line this is all i get

```
C:\Users\Mark\Desktop\Assignment 9>keytool -gencert -keystore myKeys\myKeys.keys
tore -alias mr -v
Enter keystore password:
Enter key password for <mr>
```

I do not get a new prompt, it just sits there like that on the command line. SO i cancel it and tried again a few times with no avail. Ive also toook note that in the process manager there is a keytool.exe running. I'm not sure if this is a long process or not and if i should leave it to its self for a bit or if there is a command cause that may hang the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not very long - 5 sec max. Have you tried: 
1. Look in `handle.exe` maybe somebody hold keystore?
2. Try another java version?

Comment: When i use JDK6 i dont have an option for gencert. The code above was generated using jdk7 ive tried to recreate but the same happens with all keystores on gencert.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem inside a centos 6 docker container

The command I was running is ...

```
keytool -import -noprompt -alias root -keystore ./out/keystore.jks -trustcacerts -file ./out/parent.crt -storepass ${jkspass};
```

I tried to change the Java version (to a version that works outside the container) and tried -infile as below ...

```
keytool -import -noprompt -alias root -keystore ./out/keystore.jks -trustcacerts -infile ./out/parent.csr -file ./out/parent.crt -storepass ${jkspass};
```

But nothing worked! Increasing memory did not fix issue either.
I switched to an official Java docker container.
Did not work.
I gave up in the end.

If anyone knows the fix for this please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Tripped on this too - had of course forgotten to supply the `-infile` parameter to specity the input CSR file, so keytool was sitting there waiting for input.

(There was a hint in the error shown when the command was forcibly aborted: *keytool error: java.io.IOException: Encoding bytes too short*.)

Answer (score 0):

I presume you have wrong params, I had such issue when I wrote:

```
keytool -import -alias myCert -keystore "C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\security\cacerts -file myCert.cer
```

Issue was cause I opened simbold " but not closed. To fix I've written:

```
keytool -import -alias symantec -keystore "C:\Program 
Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\lib\security\cacerts" -file symantec-root.cer
```

So I believe you have some parateters witch is incorrect

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem migrating a keystore with keytool. Even worse the generated keystore did not have the correct password.

I realized that I modified the default security providers in my JDK, adding BuncyCastle FIPS compatible.

I reverted back the original ones and everything worked fine.